# Not able to access variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ejs

I am trying to develop application with feathersjs and ejs. I have completed the connectivity part and I am able to pass data from server side, fetch it in ejs file but my next concern is that if I want to make some changes in received data like I want to add some field at client side, assign data to another variable how would I do this?

For example: I am getting a data into myVar variable and I want use myvar in my jquery script?

I have used `let data = <%= myVar %>` 
It's giving me error:
'expression expected'

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myVar= <%= myVar %>            
 </script>
```

Comment: I have tried this it's giving me an error as 'expression expected'

Comment: try to put it inside quotation marks once, `var myVar= '<%= myVar %>'`

Comment: It's type get changed.

Comment: what is the type you of it ?

Comment: res.render('home', { myVar:[2,3,4]}) - type object

Comment: previously It's object type after var myVar= '<%= myVar %>' it will be string type

Comment: I guess you have to make a for loop then to construct another javascript array to get all data from your object